# update query is updating every new value and removing previously updated values from DB

Tags: php

I am trying to update some table row values in PHP. While updating query works fine but it is updating only new values when I am hitting submit. But the old already stored same column values are removing. What can I do now?

This is my code:

```
 if((isset($row['rdocket'])) && ($row['rdocket'] != NULL)){
echo "<td> <input pattern='.{9}' class='c-font-sm' value='$row[rdocket]' readonly></input> </td>";
}
else
{
echo "<td> <input pattern='.{9}' id='test' class='c-font-sm' value='$row[rdocket]' name='p_$row[id]'></input> </td>";
}
```

Update-file.php

```
$Quantity1=$_POST['p_'.$row['id']. ''];

     $id=$row['id'];
     $store=$row['rstore'];
     echo $store;

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
            {

            echo $key;

            echo $value;

            }

     $query="update product_details SET rdocket='$Quantity1' WHERE id='$id'";
     if(mysqli_query($link, $query))
      {

      } 
     else
       {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Solved: if(!empty($quantity1)){
  $query="update product_details SET rdocket='$Quantity1' WHERE id='$id'";
  if(mysqli_query($link, $query))
      {
              
      } 
     else
       {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
if(!empty($quantity1)){ $query="update product_details SET rdocket='$Quantity1' WHERE id='$id'"; if(mysqli_query($link, $query)) { } else { echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link); } } }
```